# batch command to find and replace strings in directory names

Tags: scripting, batch-file, rename

I've created a template project called XYZ.

I'm looking to put together a batch file to copy the proect directory lock stock and barrel, then replace "XYZ" with the actual project name. I've got it working for all filenames, and their contents, the only thing left is directory names (eg rename C:\Development\Foo\ZYZ.Web\ to C:\Development\Foo\Foo.Web).

Does anybody know of a command line utility (or native commands) to make this happen?

Here's what I have so far (with the aid of the "Find And Replace Tool" at http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/)

```
REM Copy Template to destination (C:\Development\ProjectName where ProjectName is specified by the first argument)
cd C:\Development\Template\
xcopy . C:\Development\%1 /E /I

cd C:\Development\%1
REM In the destination directory, use FART to search for XYZ (within files) and replace with ProjectName 
fart --recursive *.* XYZ %1
REM In the destination directory, use FART to search for XYZ (in filenames) and replace with ProjectName
fart --recursive --filename  *.* XYZ %1
```

Comment: You are aware that we have no idea what the last two lines are supposed to do here? You have an `xcopy` and `cd` command only, with no effort AFAICT to do anything else related to a batch file except make two calls to an application. Please remember when asking questions here that we can't see your screen, read your mind, or know anything about your system that you're not providing in your question. Please edit to make it more clear what you've tried so far and what isn't working as you expect. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers Ken, have made some edits which will hopefully make things clearer.